# Java Activity: Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, methods

I have an activity which will be passed later. I need help not to pass this activity but to understand more and have methods to use for later programming activities.

So, the activity is about practicing us about Inheritance which I understand but my problem was beyond that.

```
import java.util.*;
public class sdisp extends sInfo
{
    private String cor;
    private int year;
    private String so;
    
    public String getCor()
    {
        return cor;
    }
    public void setCor(String cor) 
    {
        this.cor = cor;
    }
    public int getYear()
    {
        return year;
    }
    public void setYear(int year)
    {
        this.year = year;
    }
    public String getSo()
    {
        return so;
    }
    public void setSo(String so) 
    {
        this.so = so;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        sdisp obj=new sdisp();
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        sInfo n1=new sInfo();
        sInfo s1=new sInfo();
        sInfo g1=new sInfo();
        sInfo n2=new sInfo();
        sInfo s2=new sInfo();
        sInfo g2=new sInfo();
        sInfo n3=new sInfo();
        sInfo s3=new sInfo();
        sInfo g3=new sInfo();
        sInfo n4=new sInfo();
        sInfo s4=new sInfo();
        sInfo g4=new sInfo();
        sInfo n5=new sInfo();
        sInfo s5=new sInfo();
        sInfo g5=new sInfo();
        sdisp c1=new sdisp();
        sdisp y1=new sdisp();
        sdisp so1=new sdisp();
        sdisp c2=new sdisp();
        sdisp y2=new sdisp();
        sdisp so2=new sdisp();
        sdisp c3=new sdisp();
        sdisp y3=new sdisp();
        sdisp so3=new sdisp();
        sdisp c4=new sdisp();
        sdisp y4=new sdisp();
        sdisp so4=new sdisp();
        sdisp c5=new sdisp();
        sdisp y5=new sdisp();
        sdisp so5=new sdisp();
        
        System.out.print("Student's Name: ");
        n1.setName(input.next());
        System.out.print("Student Number: ");
        s1.setSnum(input.nextInt());
        System.out.print("Gender: ");
        g1.setGen(input.next());
        System.out.print("Course: ");
        c1.setCor(input.next());
        System.out.print("Year: ");
        y1.setYear(input.nextInt());
        System.out.print("Student Organization: ");
        so1.setSo(input.next());
        
        System.out.println("");
        
        System.out.print("Student's Name: ");
        n2.setName(input.next());
        System.out.print("Student Number: ");
        s2.setSnum(input.nextInt());
        System.out.print("Gender: ");
        g2.setGen(input.next());
        System.out.print("Course: ");
        c2.setCor(input.next());
        System.out.print("Year: ");
        y2.setYear(input.nextInt());
        System.out.print("Student Organization: ");
        so2.setSo(input.next());
        
        System.out.println("");
        
        System.out.print("Student's Name: ");
        n3.setName(input.next());
        System.out.print("Student Number: ");
        s3.setSnum(input.nextInt());
        System.out.print("Gender: ");
        g3.setGen(input.next());
        System.out.print("Course: ");
        c3.setCor(input.next());
        System.out.print("Year: ");
        y3.setYear(input.nextInt());
        System.out.print("Student Organization: ");
        so3.setSo(input.next());
        
        System.out.println("");
        
        System.out.print("Student's Name: ");
        n4.setName(input.next());
        System.out.print("Student Number: ");
        s4.setSnum(input.nextInt());
        System.out.print("Gender: ");
        g4.setGen(input.next());
        System.out.print("Course: ");
        c4.setCor(input.next());
        System.out.print("Year: ");
        y4.setYear(input.nextInt());
        System.out.print("Student Organization: ");
        so4.setSo(input.next());
        
        System.out.println("");
        
        System.out.print("Student's Name: ");
        n5.setName(input.next());
        System.out.print("Student Number: ");
        s5.setSnum(input.nextInt());
        System.out.print("Gender: ");
        g5.setGen(input.next());
        System.out.print("Course: ");
        c5.setCor(input.next());
        System.out.print("Year: ");
        y5.setYear(input.nextInt());
        System.out.print("Student Organization: ");
        so5.setSo(input.next());
        
        System.out.println("");
        
        String [] gender = new String []
                {
                        g1.getGen(), g2.getGen(), g3.getGen(), g4.getGen(), g5.getGen(),
                };
        int mcount = 0;
        int fcount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < gender.length; i++)
        {
                if (gender[i].contains("Male"))
                {
                    mcount++;
                }
                if (gender[i].contains("Female"))
                {
                    fcount++;
                }
        }
        System.out.println("Male Count: " + mcount);
        System.out.println("Female Count: " + fcount);
        
        if (mcount > fcount)
        {
            System.out.println("The majority is Male");
        }
        if (mcount < fcount)
        {
            System.out.println("The majority is Female");
        }
    }
}
```

My problem in my code is:

- Having multiple variables. I don't know what loop to use to create at least 5 students' info.

```
package gsetter;
public class sInfo 
{
    private String name;
    private int snum;
    private String gen;
    

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) 
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getSnum()
    {
        return snum;
    }
    public void setSnum(int snum)
    {
        this.snum = snum;
    }
    public String getGen()
    {
        return gen;
    }
    public void setGen(String gen) 
    {
        this.gen = gen;
    }
    

}
```

For parent class.

edit: I found out how to count male and female and find the majority.

Comment: Why have you used `getters-setters` and not a `constructor` to initialise object's values? Also, why are `course`, `year` and `so` properties defined in a separate class and not in the same class as `sInfo`?

Comment: @salazarin. We haven't/not yet learned about `constructor`, our lesson for this week was inheritance and our prof. used getters-setters so she's expecting us to use getters-setters. `course`, `year`, and `so` should be in the main display method, our prof. instructed.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally you need to use a loop and request the info kept the object sInfo.

Loop you can use a simple while loop and loop five-time. Below is a sample of how you go about

```
List<sinfo> list = new ArrayList<sinfo>()
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
int i = 0;
while( i < 5)
{
    sInfo n1=new sInfo();
      System.out.print("Student's Name: ");
        n1.setName(input.next());
        System.out.print("Student Number: ");
        n1.setSnum(input.nextInt());
        System.out.print("Gender: ");
        n1.setGen(input.next());
        System.out.print("Course: ");
        n1.setCor(input.next());
        System.out.print("Year: ");
        n1.setYear(input.nextInt());
        System.out.print("Student Organization: ");
        n1.setSo(input.next());
       list.add(n1);
       i++;
}
```

later you can use the list to retrieve back the 5 object